# Setting focus on an input field after ng-show

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is it possible set the focus of an input field via a controller once data has loaded (via $resource in this case)?

The input is hidden via ng-show until the data is returned from the API but I can't find a way to set the focus on the input. I know the ng-model name of the input, and the input name which means I could do it via jQuery, but I'd rather do it if possible the AngularJS way.

I've tried a lot of directive examples on here but they all seem to be pre-1.2 ng-focus, rely on a ng-click first from a button (can't happen in my case) or just don't work.
Any tips very gratefully received.

Comment: If you are doing this on page load, some browsers will not allow you to do this for security reasons.

Comment: I'm hoping not to, I'd much rather fire off a call when I know the data has come back from the API but I can't see to get that to work even just via jQuery.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is a simple directive that might work for you

```
<input focus-on="!!myResourceData" />

.directive('focusOn',function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function($scope,$element,$attr) {
            $scope.$watch($attr.focusOn,function(_focusVal) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    _focusVal ? $element[0].focus() :
                        $element[0].blur();
                });
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes! That's it - perhaps I wasn't doing it right as I've seen something similar but not used !! in the HTML tag. Thank you :)

Comment: Why the `setTimeout`? Is it because this digest cycle doesn't show the element yet? `$timeout` would cleanly accomplish that without resorting to arbitrary times.

Comment: @spenhil- you are exactly right. I updated the example. thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it's because I used a different version of angular or what, but I had to change `$element.focus()` to `$element[0].focus()` and the same thing for `blur()` before this worked. Other than that, it saved the day for me.

Comment: You may also need to set `$element[0].select()`, but the biggest issue is that it most likely won't work without specifying a timeout delay as both `ng-hide` and `ng-show` appear with certain animation (ng-hide-animate), so during the transition period you may not be able to set focus. Ideally you should obtain the transition period from the element, but I hope specifying some fixed (50ms) delay may work for you also.

Answer (score 32):

I have extended the answer to work with angular's `ng-show` and `ng-hide`

```
app.directive('focusOnShow', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
            if ($attr.ngShow){
                $scope.$watch($attr.ngShow, function(newValue){
                    if(newValue){
                        $timeout(function(){
                            $element[0].focus();
                        }, 0);
                    }
                })      
            }
            if ($attr.ngHide){
                $scope.$watch($attr.ngHide, function(newValue){
                    if(!newValue){
                        $timeout(function(){
                            $element[0].focus();
                        }, 0);
                    }
                })      
            }

        }
    };
})
```

All you need is to add attribute `focus-on-show`

```
<input type="text" ng-show="editing" focus-on-show />
```

Comment: This is JUST what I was looking for, awesome code you did there! Congrats!

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for as well, this is the only answer that works so far

Comment: This works fine on browser but on iPhone it is not working

Answer (score 3):

Building on koolunix's answer, if you're only looking to focus input elements it may also be useful to find the first input element that is a child of the element with the focus-on directive.

This is useful in the case of an external library abstracting the input element with directives and templates.

```
.directive('focusOn', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: -100,
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {

            $scope.$watch($attr.focusOn,
                function (_focusVal) {
                    $timeout( function () {
                        var inputElement = $element.is('input')
                            ? $element
                            : $element.find('input');

                         _focusVal ? inputElement.focus()
                                   : inputElement.blur();
                    });
                }
            );

        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use a timeout in your controller couse it hase to be rendered before 
here is a similar example with a searchbox which is hided by default

HTML:

```
<input ng-show="vm.isActive" id="searchInputBox" ></input>
<input type="button" ng-click="vm.toggleActiveInactive();">
```

Controller:

```
vm.isActive=false;
vm.toggleActiveInactive=toggleActiveInactive; // vm= viewmodel

function toggleActiveInactive() {
          if(vm.isActive==true){
            vm.isActive=false;
          }else{
            vm.isActive=true;

            $timeout(function(){     
              document.getElementById('searchBoxInput').focus()
            }, 10 );

          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version of this for Angular.io

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';

//Directive to that toggles focus from boolean value set with focusOn
@Directive({
  selector: '[focusOn]'
})
export class FocusOnDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input('focusOn') setFocus: boolean;

  constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes : SimpleChanges) {
    (!!changes.setFocus && !!changes.setFocus.currentValue) ?
      this.hostElement.nativeElement.focus() :
      this.hostElement.nativeElement.blur();
  }
}
```