# Focus() specific DOM element in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a todo app. Tasks are shown on screen using ng-repeat and their default state is showing a task's content using static controls or the basic `{{}}` binding. When a control is clicked, I hide the static view and show a different view with the same content but in a textarea for editing.

Currently when I click the static view, it switches out views but I'd like to add that it also moves focus to the textarea.

Here's my ng-repeat:

```
    <div ng-repeat="note in Todo.GetNotes()" class="brick" ng-class="{mymodal: note.Modal, nonmodal: !note.Modal}" ng-click="Todo.toggleModal(note)">
      <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--4dp demo-card-event" ng-class="[note.Color, {done: note.Done}]">
        <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
          <h4 ng-hide="note.Modal"><!-- Static View -->
            {{ note.Content }}
          </h4>
          <div ng-show="note.Modal" class="EditView"><!-- Editable View -->
            <textarea ng-model="note.Content" class="EditContent" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__menu">
          <button ng-hide="note.Modal" class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" ng-class="{'done-check': !note.Done}" ng-click="Todo.toggleDone(note)">
            <i class="material-icons">done</i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I'm using Material Design Lite so it's got a lot of extra classes but the short of it is that when you click on an ng-repeat element, it will toggle if that element is Modal or not. If it's Modal, it's editable and the textarea is visible.

My `Todo.toggleModal` is currently just one line:

```
note.Modal = !note.Modal
```

I think that's where I want to add a call to `focus()` on the textarea I'm displaying but I'm not sure how I can access the specific textarea for the note I clicked on. How would I do this?

Comment: Perhaps something like this, placed on your textarea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24416690/624590

Comment: Interesting! I'll try it.

Comment: @DRobinson This worked fantastically after a small change (`$element[0].focus()` instead of `$element.focus()` same for `blur()`). Submit it as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: I don't think that I added anything new here, and so it doesn't feel like a valid "answer". In fact, this question might be considered a duplicate of that one, just slightly different semantically. Consider up-voting the other persons answer in the link instead :)