# ng-repeat and focus inputs

Tags: angularjs, focus, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of buttons and inputs generated by ng-repeat, and I want the following functionality :
when I click a button it focuses on the following input.

If I use:

```
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-sm chat-option chat-option-add but-0" style="padding: 0px;border-radius: 50%;"></button>
        <input type="text" class="input-0" style="color:black;">
    </div>

    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-sm chat-option chat-option-add but-1" style="padding: 0px;border-radius: 50%;"></button>
        <input type="text" class="input-1" style="color:black;">
    </div>`enter code here`
 <script>
    $('.but-0').click(function () {
        $('.input-0').focus();
    });
    </script>

    <script>
    $('.but-1').click(function () {
        $('.input-1').focus();
    });
    </script>
```

it works fine.
but if i want to use ng-repeat with those scripts :

```
   <div ng-repeat="f in testFocus">
            <button class="btn btn-sm chat-option chat-option-add but-{{$index}}" style="padding: 0px;border-radius: 50%;"></button>
            <input type="text" class="input-{{$index}}" style="color:black;">

        </div>
```

it doesn't work for me - clicking the button does not focus the input at all.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind event to an already existing element.

```
<button class="btn btn-sm chat-option chat-option-add but-{{$index}}" style="padding: 0px;border-radius: 50%;">button</button>
<input type="text" class="input-{{$index}}" style="color:black;" />
```

```
$(document).on('click', '.but-0', function () {
    $('.input-0').focus();
});

$(document).on('click', '.but-1', function () {
    $('.input-1').focus();
});
```

In angular you can do it more elegantly by taking help of `ng-click` on the button.

```
<button class="btn btn-sm chat-option chat-option-add" ng-click="buttonClicked($index)" style="padding: 0px;border-radius: 50%;">button</button>
<input type="text" class="input-{{$index}}" style="color:black;" />
```

```
$scope.buttonClicked = function($index) {
    $('.input-'+ $index).focus();
}
```

See this [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/jhKvIDeqKcJcXuO1V3I4?p=preview)

Comment: thank you foe the answer, it works fine that way, but im having problems if i use ng-show. i cant see why it harms the binding.                                                                               <button class="btn btn-sm chat-option chat-option-add" ng-click="Show=true; buttonClicked($index)"></button>                         <input type="text" class="input-{{$index}}" style="color:black;" ng-model="value" ng-show="Show" />

Comment: Use `$timeout` to execute this code `$('.input-'+ $index).focus();` after `ng-hide` is removed. See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JLJLlzcOoSgeZ5TmPFHK?p=preview). By the way, you can also use a directive to focus element when `ng-show` is true. For this one, see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415168/setting-focus-on-an-input-field-after-ng-show).